# How does battery make charge in conductor move?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, batteries

A wire with resistance is connected to the two ends of a battery, how does the battery cause the free charges in conductor, the wire, move? I know the battery provide a potential difference. But how this potential difference cause the charges in conductors move? Does it create a E field in the conductor, which cause free charges move? It seems battery doesn’t create E field outside of it but free charges need E field to move in a direction together producing current. And is it right that a battery doesn’t provide charge to a circuit, it just makes the free charges in conductors move around the closed circuit, making these charges pass through itself?

Answer (score 6):

The potential difference, or voltage $V$, produces an electric field $E = - \nabla V$ between the battery terminals connected by the circuit. In this way, the electrons in the conductor begin to move according to the force they are subjected to, generating a current, $i$. The resistance of the circuit is defined as $R = \frac{V}{i}$.

On the other hand, the creation of a stationary current also requires an electromotive force, provided by the battery, which is the way to maintain the potential difference.

Comment: I know there is a field in the battery. But how does a battery create in a wire? I mean without wire, does it still create a field outside, for instance, in air? If not, how does it create a field in a wire as long as it connects to the two ends immediately?

Comment: @XiangLi, when there is a potential difference between two points, there is an electric field along the path between them, no matter what path you choose...through the battery or through wires connected between the battery terminals or through the space between the wires doesn't matter.

Comment: Is there always a electric field outside battery whether a wire connects to it or not?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to imagine what's going on here.

A battery is a device that generates extra electrons which it pushes out one terminal (where they pile up, ready to go) while eating electrons, which it sucks up out of the other terminal (leaving it with an electron deficit). This tendency is measured as a voltage or potential difference across the two terminals.

If we connect the two terminals together through a load resistor, the extra electrons now have a path they can follow which ends at the terminal that wants to suck them up, and a current is established through the load resistor.

Keep this picture in mind as you work through geofisue's explanation which uses the electric field treatment and you should have no worries.

Answer (score 0):

The gradient of potential is non zero. Hence any charged particle (which can couple with EM field) will feel non zero force. Now the direction depends on the potential and the type of charged particle.